# Asterisk character (no wildcard) on conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-sheets

I have a sheet with following values on column A:

```
    [         A           ]
[1] Dead line
[2] 15 days remaining***
[3] Dead
[4] 131 days remaining*
[5] 80 days remaining**
```

I would like to use conditional formatting on column A so:

- when only 1 asterisk appears: green cell background
- when only 2 asterisks appear: yellow cell background
- when only 3 asterisks appear: orange cell background
- when column is `Dead`: red cell background

But when I set to `A:A` the rule `text contains` with value `*` to paint with green background, the whole column is painted with green background, regardless of other rules.

I see that the `*` is interpreted as an wildcard to "any string", but I would like to threat each `*` as one asterisk character only.

Someone can help me?

PS:

- The final sheet must use this format of data on column A, with those awful asterisks (no way to change);
- `A1` is a header;
- It is only a sample. Original sheet has so many lines...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve your desired results by putting a tilde, `~` in front of the asterisk as an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), if you put the conditional formatting rules in the order listed below.

First, create the one for orange when three asterisks occur using `text contains` and then specifying `~*~*~*`. Select `custom` to pick an orange background. Then create the one for two asterisks using `text contains` and `~*~*` picking yellow for the color. Then for the next rule create one for green  with `text contains` and `~*`. Then you can create the one with a red background using `text is exactly` specifying `Dead` and picking red for the background.

[image: asterisk conditional formatting rules]

You should then see the following:

[image: Asterisk conditional formatting applied]

Comment: Can't escape on assigning as the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and more versatile solution is to select custom formula and use regular expression matching with `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"[^\*]\*{2}[^\*]")` looking for asterisk sequences of the precise length 2 (to match 1 or 3 replace the number two accordingly).

Comment: How this could be applied to solve the specific case of the OP?

Comment: @Rubén: I've added a formula. Escaping the asterisk works in this particular case but is of limited versatility. OP just wanted A solution, not necessarily the one closest to what they were thinking of.